# Duplicating rows in database

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, vb.net, .net-3.5

For some reason, the if statement below is not working

```
''# count if records with this user already exist in the database below
objSQLCommand = New SqlCommand("select count(id) as record_count from table1 where user = @strUser", objSQLConnection)
objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@strUser", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = strUser

objSQLCommand.Connection.Open()
intRecordCount = CType(objSQLCommand.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
objSQLCommand.Connection.Close()

''# duplicate default rows in database if username not in database
If intRecordCount = 0 Then
    Response.Write(intRecordCount)

    objSQLCommand = New SqlCommand("insert into table1 (heading, user) select heading, @strUser as user from table1 where defaults = @intDefault", objSQLConnection)
    objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@strUser", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = strUser
    objSQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@intDefault", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = 1
End If
```

Response.Write(intRecordCount) returns a 0 if 0 records are found and it returns 2 if i manually insert 2 rows for the user in the database.

But for some reason, the if statement does not work. If I run the "insert select" query manually, it works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not executing the second SQL insert command as you do in:

```
intRecordCount = CType(objSQLCommand.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
```

Comment: It is supposed to only duplicate rows if the user does not exist

Comment: That was it.  Thanks!  Can't accept answer for another few minutes though.